# The most proper model for combining both input types(TIME_SERIES_INPUT and AUXILIARY(static)_INPUTS)?

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm

So I have searched a few posts and Issue posts about the reshaping problem but none of these solutions seems to work for me so far.

The goal of the project: predicting the week-based sales by each store and SKU(the properties of clothes: e.g. colour/size).

The structure of the dataset is like following:

`Week, store_id, color, size, last_week_sales, last_2week_sales_(sales two weeks),actual_sales(the one we want to predict)
1, 341, red, LL, 0, 1, 1
1, 341, yellow, M, 2, 4, 2
1, 341, blue, S, 2, 2, 3
2, 342, blue, M, 2, 3, 1
2, 342, green, S, 2, 3, 2`

So for each week, every record is unique by the combination of the features(properties of the clothes and the store_id etc.)

The number of records for each week is not the same.

**Update on 8-23-2018:**

I tried the fully-connected NN, yet the correctness is about 75% which can't be improved in various ways. I wondered whether there's another way around dealing this issue, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'reshaping problem' stems from a lack of understanding of your own data and prediction goals. LSTMs (and RNNs in general) expect a sequence-of-vectors data structure. Essentially, you want to model some function f(x) where your features are time varying, x=x(t), therefore f(x) may be rewritten as f(t). This is not particularly evident in your sample dataset, as only a small subset of your features (the sales) are time-varying.

What you could do would be to consider a **single time slice** as a vector whose elements are the static features (color, store id, whatever) PLUS a single instance of sales. Then a **full sample** would be a matrix consisting of N vertically stacked time slices, where N the count of time slices you have. Many instances of these samples would be a **batch**, i.e. a 3-dimensional tensor which is the expected input of a recurrent network.

If you're not just doing this for the sake of experimentation and learning, you should keep in mind that this is a bad approach. Your features do not have any sort of temporal structure and, intuitively, they should not have any predictive potential of next week's sales. Additionally, using a RNN here is an overkill and you will certainly be overfitting your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This makes sense cuz I'm quite confused how could static features being necessary to be reshaped. Well, the question becomes, what kind of method is more proper for predicting sales using static features(colour, size etc.) and time-varying features(last week sales etc.)? Thanks!

Comment: sorry, a few more questions. 1. Is there a way other than RNN for predicting sales combining static features(colour, size etc.) and time-varying features(last week sales)?  They are about the same amount. 2. Say if I only have one product, and at each time point it has a bunch of time-varying features, then RNN is the proper choice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. RNNs **can** do that already, I'm just doubting the necessity of them given the dataset's simplicity. Alternatively, you could apply a transformation of your static features and convert them into a 'seed' vector to be used as the RNNs initial hidden state 2. In theory yes, but essentially this doesn't make a difference; in one case you assume a universal function for all products, parametric over the static features, and in the other case you're modeling a unique function per product.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, really appreciated. So given the dataset's simplicity, is there a way other than **RNN** for predicting the sales? If using RNN, I'm not quite sure I got the way of transformation... for instance, X = (**s**tatic + **t**iming features) x n(no. of samples) Y=vector of actual_sales.  _convert **s**tatic features into a 'seed' vector_, more specifically, does it mean X will be like (**s** x **t**) ? Sorry, I'm kind of confused. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can just use a regular fully connected network, given your current dataset. Otherwise, in the RNN case: X = [X(0), X(1), ..., X(N)], where X(t) = [static features, sales at timestep t], and y = [sales at timestep t+1]. In the hidden encoding case, you need a transformation [static features] → h(0), where h(0) the hidden layer initialization

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The fully-connected network got a decent result at 75% accuracy, which couldn't be improved so far... I wondered how lstm's result could be. As mentioned above, the transformation of [static features] → h(0), to my understanding, the input would be 4 timesteps given h(0), which is the combination of static features. So my questions become: 1. does it matter if there're multiple same time points given different conditions(h(0))? 2. If not, then is there any more specific keras lines on how to realize this initialization? thanks for your patience.